# Method if boolean true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a coupons schema that looks like this:

```
 create_table "coupons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "discount_code",                 null: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "amount",        default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "used",          default: false, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_coupons_on_user_id"
 end
```

I have two questions. How can I not allow:

1. the coupon with `used` set to true to be used again?
2. to change `used` from false to true once it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a branch to your conditional:

```
if (current_user.id == @coupon.user_id) && !@coupon.used
  <valid coupon redeem logic>
elsif @coupon.used
  <return coupon used message>
else
  <coupon invalid logic>
end
```

Comment: It works!!!:)))  Thank you @moveson!!! I have been trying to solve this for the past few hours!